# Please explain the value of the path attribute for a file provider in android

Tags: android, file, provider

Here is the file_path xml

```
<paths>
<files-path name="images" path="."/>
```

What does the dot do here? From what I know `files-path` returns the `files` directory. Why put a dot here?

Comment: The dot means -as usually- in the directory itself.

Comment: `files-path returns the files directory. ` No files-path does not return anything. It refers to getFilesDir() which happens to deliver a path ending with a folder named files. Like /data/data/<package>/files.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen people put in a `/` like this `path="/"`. It seems to me you can put all sorts of symbols there and they all point to the `files/` directory that `getFilesDir` returns. Am I correct?

Comment: You cannot just put there all kind of symbols. It should be an existing path starting in the files folder. But experiment. You can check all by calling getUriForFile() and looking at .toString() value of it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. The dot or / stands for the current working directory, which is the one returned by getFilesDir.